# When did firefox for android remove eme/drm support

Tags: android, firefox, mobile

I've created a web application using spotifys web playback sdk and it needs eme/drm support in order to work. (spotify says that mobile isnt supported but i found a way) I know that the recent releases of firefox on android dont have this support.

I am currently using a nightly version of firefox from back in october of 2018 and it is able to play the music on mobile fine.

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mobile/nightly/2018/08/2018-08-31-11-06-20-oak-android-api-16/

I am just wondering if anyone knows when firefox removed the support for eme so I could use the most up to date browser possible all the while maintaining playback support on android.

Answer (score 1):

In firefox url type about:config, search for media.eme and set value to true.